# R values; Splitting strings equally into 2 parts

Tags: r

I currently have a list of strings in R. I need to split each string into half. How do I go about it using stringr package? Do I have to do a for loop to go through all items?

print(items) ; current items that I have..

Input:
[1] "Apple JuiceApple Juice" "BananaBanana" "Carrot JuiceCarrot Juice" "Donut DonutDonut Donut" "elephant226elephant226" "fruitpunchfruitpunch"

print(items) ; end results that I want..

Output:
[1] "Apple Juice" "Banana" "Carrot Juice" "Donut Donut" "elephant226" "fruitpunch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `stringr` you can use `str_sub` to divide string into half based on it's length.

```
items <-  c("Apple JuiceApple Juice", "BananaBanana", "Carrot JuiceCarrot Juice" ,"Donut DonutDonut Donut", "elephant226elephant226", "fruitpunchfruitpunch")

stringr::str_sub(items, 1, nchar(items)/2)
#[1] "Apple Juice"  "Banana"       "Carrot Juice" "Donut Donut"  "elephant226"  "fruitpunch"
```

In base R, you can use `substr`/`substring` similarly :

```
substr(items, 1, nchar(items)/2)
```